# ER diagram to Object Relational Database Design

Tags: relational-database, entity-relationship, erd

Is there any tool which take ER diagram as input and generate Object Relational Database Design in return? More specially is it possible with mysql workbench?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Power Designer  [(sse description)](http://www.sybase.com/content/1035420/PD11_ds.pdf) looks like it will do what you want.  It's kinda pricey.